# Windows Python 2.5 Traceback.py Nonetype error

Tags: python, windows, trace, python-2.5

Hello I am running Python 2.5 on Windows and whenever my application gets an exception rather than seeing the debug information I get an error inside of the traceback.py file itself. Anyone know a fix for this mb a patch or replacement file.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python25\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 744, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 630, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 426, in format
    record.exc_text = self.formatException(record.exc_info)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 398, in formatException
    traceback.print_exception(ei[0], ei[1], ei[2], None, sio)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\traceback.py", line 126, in print_exception
    lines = format_exception_only(etype, value)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\traceback.py", line 176, in format_exception_only
    stype = etype.__name__
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__name__'
```

===EDIT===

Found same error in mailing list here outdated answer it seems

http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2006-September/068975.html

Comment: maybe you could put up an example code that demonstrates this error?

Comment: It is hard to do because instead of a stack trace I get this. I am assuming this is a problem with python's traceback.py rather than my code because everything above has to do with python25\lib\

Comment: if you aren't able to pick apart which section gives you the error (which can be done simply by commenting out sections of your code until this happens again, then recreating that small feature), we can't really help you. I'm going to probably say it has something more to do with what your code is doing rather than pythons. You can easily be doing stuff that would invalidate pythons built-in exception handling...

Comment: You are probably making a mistake with your custom exception handling

Comment: I agree with @g19fanatic, it's much more likely the bug is in your code... somewhere. Unfortunately this is in class of bugs which are difficult to debug.

You say "whenever it gets an exception", could you put in an `assert 1==2` line somewhere and if you get the same report. It seems more likely that you are just seeing the *same* exception again and again.

Answer (score 2):

Possible causes:

1. Calling `logging.exception()` when there is no active exception
2. Calling a logging function with `exc_info=1`, when there is no active exception.
3. Calling a logging function with `exc_info=(None, None, None)` to a logging function (e.g. if doing the exception logging manually).

You should not use `logging.exception` outside of an except block.

The exception is caused by a `None` exception type passed to `traceback.print_exception`, meaning that there is no active exception to process.

Meanwhile, the newsgroup posting you linked to indicates that it was a regression in the standard library that resulted in that particular traceback. You may want to try upgrading your Python to 2.5.1, which fixed this particular problem.

Comment: thanks. yea I am brand new to this project so not having the file reference in the exception is basically impossible to find the root cause

Comment: You could also consider upgrading Python to 2.5.1, as they put in a patch which would prevent this particular exception.